# How to properly write a python cgi script that receives json data?

Tags: python, tomcat, cgi

My current test python script does something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
myjson = json.loads(data)
```

The problem is that even if this worked in some case, on others it seems to block, probably at the read().

For some other reasons I am forced to use tomcat to the cgi scripts, not sure if this matters anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to check the content length before reading and limit the number of byte read by `sys.stdin.read()`. See [`cgi.parse_header()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_header).

**Update:**

Your incoming data comes through the environment which is populated by the web server. It is accessible in `os.environ`.

```
import os
from cgi import parse_header
os.environ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
parse_header(os.environ['Content-Type'])
# returns ('text/html', {'charset': 'utf-8'})
```

So in your CGI script you need (roughly):

```
import os, cgi, sys
cl, _ = parse_header(os.environ['Content-Length'])
data = sys.stdin.read(int(cl))
```

Comment: Could you please post a basic code example, the cgi module documentation does not provide any example of using parse_header(), where should I get the parameter that it requires?